# What is the algorithm of block selection using Target Difficulty?

Tags: block, difficulty

Suppose below is target difficulty:

```
0x0000CDEF0A000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

So result value must lower than target to select block.

So, If Miner 'A' found:

```
0x000000000000000000000000076898778ABEFDC34798734590349843BDCAE854
```

Will miner 'A' can satisfy target difficulty or not?

And if not then please tell me the reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The test is that in order to be a valid proof of work, the hash found must be numerically less than or equal to the target.  That is certainly true of the hash found by Miner A in your example.

Comment: Thanks, Still I am not clear.

I referred http://blockexplorer.com/ some completed blocks,and found "Hash Value" has same number of Previous zeros as target has. I mean if Target has 4 previous zero(0x000043AbC..),then found hash has same number of zero(0x000024C...).

Why all the Found hash same number of zeros? It may also generate more than 4 zeros and satisfy less than target.

Comment: @tushar: It certainly could have 4 more zeros, but this will only happen 1/65536 of the time, so it's not surprising we rarely see it.